# How to convert number to String

Tags: elm

Is there a function like `number -> String` in Elm which formats number to `String`? Not looking for specific `Int` or `Float` type but a general converting function for "typeclass" `number`.

Comment: sadly Elm does not have typeclasses. Look at Purescript if you want a strongly-typed pure functional compile-to-JS frontend logic that also has typeclasses.

Comment: One way to investigate this question is to search `number -> String` on https://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/ (which will show that there aren't any packages exposing a function with that type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

---

Generally the `number` typeclass exists mostly so that mathematical operators work for both `Int` and `Float`. I would recommend not trying to program generically against `number` in your own code, but just pick the appropriate one (that's usually `Float`, unless you're counting).

Answer (score 15):

Posting this here because this comes up when you google "elm int to string".

The correct answer for converting an `int` to a `string` is super simple: `String.fromInt`

https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/String#fromInt

Answer (score 4):

While individual methods exist to convert from float/int to string, there is no common method to do so since version 0.19 of elm. As of today, you can use the `Debug.toString` [method](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Debug#toString) to do so. But the debug module does not work for production builds.

So, if your end goal is to make a production ready code, you will have to make your own code to typecast, else `Debug.toString` should work for you.